# My check for an input in a list is not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

So I am trying to check whether or not an input is an item in a 2d array but the check is not working properly and is returning false for any input.

CODE:

```
menu = [["Cheese Pizza", 8], ["Pepperoni Pizza", 10], ["Meat Lovers Pizza", 12], ["Garlic Bread", 5], ["Chicken Wings", 6]]

write("How many unique items would you like to order? \n")
itemno = int(input().strip())
for i in range(itemno):
    write("What item would you like to order? \n")
    for k, (item, price) in enumerate(menu):
        write("{} \n".format(item))
    while item not in menu:
        item = str(input().title())
        if item not in menu:
            write("Sorry this item does not seem to be available on the menu. \n")
```

EXAMPLE:

[image]

EDIT: For those of you wondering write is a self defined command just to make the text print out in a cool way.

Comment: In order to print a line on screen, why are you using `write()`. Is not `print()` used for that. Help me understand if I am missing anything. Also, your code is not indented properly and  in python, indentation is very crucial.

Comment: sorry yes i should clarify that, write is a self defined function that writes every message character by character to look nice. Thank you for reminding me I should add that into the description.

Comment: @Shraddha what part do you believe has not been indented properly sorry?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After the first line, correct me if my understanding is wrong that you have defined a function named `write()` that prints stuffs in some desired way. But, then since `write()` is still part of the main block of the program, it should be aligned with the first line.

Comment: oh sorry no that is accidental i need to re-edit the code it seems

Comment: sorry on my screen the code keeps changing indentations by itself and i am very confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218392/discussion-between-umair-ahmed-and-shraddha).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the check using the `in` clause, you will have to specify the whole list

```
>>> menu = [["Cheese Pizza", 8], ["Pepperoni Pizza", 10], ["Meat Lovers Pizza", 12], ["Garlic Bread", 5], ["Chicken Wings", 6]]
>>> "Cheese Pizza" in menu
False
>>> ["Cheese Pizza", 8] in menu
True
```

For your particular usecase, I would suggest moving the menu to a `dict` rather than using it as a 2d list

```
menu = {
    "Cheese Pizza" : 8,
    "Pepperoni Pizza" : 10,
    "Meat Lovers Pizza" : 12,
    "Garlic Bread" : 5,
    "Chicken Wings" : 6
}
print("How many unique items would you like to order? \n")
itemno = int(input().strip())
for i in range(itemno):
    print("What item would you like to order? \n")
    for item, price in menu.items():
        print("{} \n".format(item))
    item_input=""
    while item_input not in menu:
        item_input = str(input().title())
        if item_input not in menu:
            print("Sorry this item does not seem to be available on the menu. \n")
```

Comment: Ah i see, sorry I havent used python in a couple years but you can have a list as an item in a dictionary right? I need to be able to append a quantity later through a user input.

Comment: Yes that is correct, you can have a list as the value to a particular key in the dictionary